# how to enable comments only to subscribed users

Tags: 7, comments, notifications, nodes

I'm creating a site for events where people can subscribe themselves to a single one.
Now, I'm using [Node Registration](https://drupal.org/project/node_registration) module to allow users to subscribe. I would like to know if it is possible to enable comments of a particular event only to users who are members of it. Is there a module to do this? I tried with rules module but i couldn't...

Comment: do anonymous users allowed to register to events?

Comment: No, only registered users can subscribe to an event...if you are already a site member you can add comments only to events where you are subscribed in..

Comment: check the answer added below if that helps you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a programmatic way to do this, add this code to your custom module

**NOTE:**

In the following code my content type name is article, change it to yours.

Also this code can not handle functionality for anonymous user as I couldn find a way to track if anonymous user is already registered or not.

```
/**
  * Helper function to check if user is registered to a given event node or node.
 */
function check_if_user_is_registered($node, $uid) {
   $return = FALSE;
   $registrations = node_registration_load_multiple(FALSE, array(
      'uid' => $uid,
      'nid' => $node->nid,
      'cancelled' => 0,
    ));
  if(is_array($registrations)) {
    foreach($registrations as $registration) {
      if($registration->author_uid == $uid) {
        $return = TRUE;
      }
    }
  }
  return $return;
}

/**
  *  Implements hook_node_load().
 */
function MYMODULENAME_node_load($nodes, $types) {
  global $user;
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    if($node->type == "article") {
      $access = check_if_user_is_registered($node,$user->uid);
      if(!$access) {
       $node->comment = 0; // to close comments
      }   
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but I have only used existing modules (node registration modules), not custom ones...How can i do? Do you suggest me to create a new one by myself?

Comment: check this http://www.packtpub.com/article/creating-your-first-module-drupal-module-development

Comment: basically you need two files mymodulename.info which tells drupal about your custom module and mymodulename.module where your funcitonality lays down. remember "mymodulename" should be replaced by a standard name mostly the name should revolve around the functionality it adds.So the above code in the answer will go to the your .module file and the link shared in the comments can tell you what to add in the .info file

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now i'm going to read it. I hope to understand..

Comment: sure let me know if you have issues

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work...I put into the file .info all the informations of the module as name, dependencies, etc. etc. Then I put your code in .module and I have replaced "mymodulename" with the new name module I created; I have also replaced "article" with my content type(ads_contests) but nothing.
I can activate the module but after that I see php code at the top of the page..

Comment: Did you miss adding the php tags in the .module file

Comment: oops..stupid mistake! I'm sorry!

Comment: It works! Thank you! Now I'd want to insert a date control..if the contest is taking place, comments are open only for its  subscribed users..should I use the time() function?

Comment: yes change  if(!$access) to something like       if(!$access && time() > $content_time) // where $contest_time will be given to your code